# How do I merge two tables in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1

I have two tables

table 1:

```
name| count
xxx  | 1
yyyy | 2
zzzz | 3
```

table 2:

```
name |count
xxx  | 1
aaa  | 5
```

I want the resulting table to be like the following
table:

```
name | count
xxx  | 1
yyyy | 2
zzzz | 3
aaa  | 5
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Can't this be done with a simple query that checks for the ID (name is this case) and does a join?

Answer (score 56):

You should use UNION.

```
select * from table1
union
select * from table2
```

To insert into table 1:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1
select * from table2 
    where not exists(
            select * from table1 
                 where name=TABLE2.Name 
                       and count=TABLE2.Count
                     )
```

Comment: hi unoin gives the expexted result but table 1 remains same i need to insert the values in table1 whatever new in table2

Comment: I've added a query to insert into table1

Comment: This looks like it doesn't handle deletes so if table 2 didn't have something that table 1 had, it wouldn't delete it, which I would expect from a merge. Maybe I'm looking at that wrong.

Answer (score 18):

We don't need any special MERGE/UPSERT Command.

1. To merge rows from one table into the other.

   ```
   INSERT INTO table1
     (SELECT * FROM table2
      WHERE name NOT IN
          (SELECT name FROM table1));
   ```
2. For creating new table from old tables.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE new_table AS
   (SELECT * FROM table1
   UNION
   SELECT * FROM table2);
   ```

Answer (score 12):

Merging tables and "upserting" is such a common db task that it's worth updating this answer for 2021. Assuming the tables are identical, the easiest and fastest way in postgresql:

```
INSERT INTO table1
    SELECT * FROM table2
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

Before populating the upsert values, create 'table2' as an empty copy of 'table1' to ensure all the columns are the same:

```
CREATE TABLE "table2"
    AS TABLE "table1"
    WITH NO DATA;
```

Presto.

Comment: WITH NO DATA, how long have I not know this, sigh.  I always say 'where primary_key_col = 'asdfasdfasdf' or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check whether this is working in your developer,

```
MERGE INTO table1 x
USING table2 b
ON ( x.name=b.name and x.count=b.count)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (x.name,x.count)VALUES(b.name,b.count);
```

Comment: I don't think PostgreSQL supports MERGE INTO, maybe in version 9.5?

Comment: Nope: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/unsupported-features-sql-standard.html See F312 F313 and F314.

Comment: This is SQL server TSQL syntax.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/attachment/23520/sql-merge.html

Comment: the merge statement appears to be slated for release in v 15

Comment: @zhongxiao37 I believe it is an ANSI syntax - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` is much faster than `UNION`. At least look into the `explain` statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **merge vertically** two tables obtained from queries **with *join* and/or filters**, you should use parenthesis:

```
(select id, name
from client c
inner join company c2 on c.company_id = c2.id
where c2.country_id = 1)
union
(select id, name
from supplier s
inner join company c on s.company_id = c.id
where c.country_id = 1)
```